# Simple XAML to XAML page navigation

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to simply navigate from one .xaml page to another. I realize that the navigation template is built for this but I do not want the mainpage header / content below feel that it brings. Using a blank Silverlight application (C#) I want to move from Page1.xaml to Page2.xaml using a hyperlink button.

On Page1.xaml I have a hyperlink button like this:

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="Preview Report" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="98,296,377,21" Name="hyperlinkButton1" NavigateUri="/Page2.xaml" />
```

this doesn't seem to work. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a navigation frame in your MainPage in order to support this.  Start with blank Silverlight Application.

Modify MainPage.xaml to look like:-

```
<UserControl x:Class="StackoverflowSpikes.NavPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"              
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <navigation:Frame Source="/Page1.xaml" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Add two or more Navigation Page's to your project.  Now you can add `HyperLinkButton` elements to them.